# obtain information from API javascript

Tags: javascript, api

I wanted to know if there was a way I can receive information from API through JavaScript. I'm currently trying to use the information from API from www.openweathermap.org but I'm not sure how I can do it with JS. I currently tried

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("GET", "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?
lat=38.892634199999996&lon=-77.0689154", false);
xhr.send();

console.log(xhr);
```

which responds and sends me information in JS Object format:

```
{ response: {"coord":{"lon":-77.04,"lat":38.9},"weather":[{"id":800,"main":"Clear",
"description":"sky is clear","icon":"01d"}],"base":"cmc stations","main":{
   "temp":301.51,"pressure":1016,"humidity":51,"temp_min":299.15,"temp_max":304.15},
"wind":{"speed":2.6,"deg":360},"clouds":{"all":1},"dt":1436565479,
"sys":{"type":1,"id":1325,"message":0.008,"country":"US","sunrise":1436521925,
"sunset":1436574893},"id":4140963,"name":"Washington, D. C.","cod":200}\n',
  responseText: '{"coord":{"lon":-77.04,"lat":38.9},"weather":[{"id":800,
"main":"Clear","description":"sky is clear","icon":"01d"}],"base":"cmc stations",
"main":{"temp":301.51,"pressure":1016,"humidity":51,"temp_min":299.15,
"temp_max":304.15},"wind":{"speed":2.6,"deg":360},"clouds":{"all":1},
"dt":1436565479,"sys":{"type":1,"id":1325,"message":0.008,"country":"US",
"sunrise":1436521925,"sunset":1436574893},"id":4140963,"name":"Washington, D. C.","cod":200} }
```

I tried console.log(xhr.response.coord) and console.log(xhr.responseText.coord) as an example and both comes out undefined. Do I need to do something else to print out the information?

I know you can use $.get(URL, function()) to receive the information via JQUERY but is there a way I can do it just JS?

Comment: What do you get when you log xhr.response?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should parse the string as a JSON object. Like this:

```
var data = JSON.parse(xhr.response);
console.log(data.coord);
```

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the response handler

```js
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
// when the async call finishes, we need to check what happened
xhr.onreadystatechange=function(){
  // if it finished without errors
  if (xhr.readyState==4 && xhr.status==200){
    // we get the data
    var data = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
    // this should be your json
    //console.log(data.response.coord);
    document.getElementById('response').innerHTML = xhr.responseText;
  }
};

// NOTE! for demo purposes I'm using another api query that does not require an api key, change this to your api url
xhr.open("GET", "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=London,uk", false);
xhr.send();
```

```html
<div id="response"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your response is in JSON so you need to parse it first.

Use `JSON.parse(xhr.response)` to parse the response.

Like this:

```
JSON.parse(xhr.response)["coord"]["lat"]
JSON.parse(xhr.response)["coord"]["lon"]
```